# How to click a javascript button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

How do I click the size button and add to cart using selenium web driver and python?

This is for the website below

http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/dri-fit-cool-tailwind-stripe-running-shirt/pid-10739300/pgid-11072108

Please let me know if there is anything I should paste in here related to the size button.

Comment: Sorry I am actually using webdriver plus the firefox selenium IDE plugin.

Answer (score 8):

A python example:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/dri-fit-cool-tailwind-stripe-running-shirt/pid-10739300/pgid-11072108")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('theClassName')[0].click()")
```

Please note that `('theClassName')[0]` will match the first element with `theClassName`, you may need to increase the number.

---

To get the element by its ID, use:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/dri-fit-cool-tailwind-stripe-running-shirt/pid-10739300/pgid-11072108")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('theIdName').click()")
```

Comment: I am experimenting with this example code, but I think I am using the incorrect class name because I'm getting "WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point "  What class name should I be using?

Comment: `store.nike.com` may have changed their code and you'll have to take a look at the source code.