# Click not working for selenium in web scraping using python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I am working on web scraping using selenium(python). There is chunk on code which is really long. So , i am using loops. When i am running the code lines separately, it is working fine but when i am using the loop, its not working. Here are the two errors:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (862, 13). Other element would receive the click: <div class="skycom_container">...</div>
(Session info: chrome=46.0.2490.80)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (924, 786). Other element would receive the click: <div id="silentUIblocker" style="display: block;"></div>
(Session info: chrome=46.0.2490.80)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

Are these common or specific errors??
This is happening just before using the click() statement.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\name\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (3)\chromedriver.exe')


driver.get('https://www.sky.com/shop/beta?s_tnt=87085:31:0')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/article/button/div[1]/div[2]/div/h2').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/section/div/div/div/div/div[1]/article/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="polaris"]/div/div/div/section/div/div[2]/a[2]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dsl-postcode"]').send_keys("E11 2LX")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dsl-check-landline"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dsl-addresses"]/option[2]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dsl-multiple-address-select"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dsl-numberPortingNo"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dsl-number-porting-submit"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="summaryBackLink"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="oneOffCostToolTip"]').click()
bb_pack = ["SKY_FIBRE_CAPPED", "BB_MAX"]
for i in bb_pack:
  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="productButtonControls_%s"]/label' % i).click()
  bb_name1.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="productButtonControls_%s"]/label' % i).text)
  pack = ["ANYTIME_EXTRA", "INTERNATIONAL_EXTRA"]
  for j in pack:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="productButtonControls_ST_%s"]/label' % j).click()
    bb_name2.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="productButtonControls_ST_%s"]/label' % j).text)
    #more details in this loop
```

Comment: Consider upgrading your `Chrome` to 60.0 & `chromedriver` to 2.30. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Comment: This generally happens when Dom is getting updated and webdriver tries to click or another hidden element is blocking your element. Try giving wait/sleeps between the clicks.

Comment: @Debanjan, upgrading is not an option for me at all.

Comment: @Prakash, i tried that, i have almost 400 such cases, applying sleep will take really long time. Is there any other option?

Comment: post your code. Solution is probably 1. `import time` 2. one line before the error comes put `time.sleep(10)`.

Comment: @DebanjanB check your exception, it is showing other element would receive the click: <div id="silentUIblocker" style="display: block;"></div>  so, wait for this UI block div to disappear/elementNotVisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fluent wait as below. It will wait till your element is not ready on page:-

```
WebElement waitsss(WebDriver driver, By elementIdentifier){
     Wait<WebDriver> wait =
                new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                 .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                             .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

return wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>()
        {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                   return driver.findElement(elementIdentifier);
            }
            });
}
```

The wait should work for you. If still the problem exists then use JavascriptExecutor . It will operate directly through JS. It should work. I am giving an example to click any element using JavascriptExecutor

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfd"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

I just saw you are using python, in python, it should be something like below :-

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

The script should be like below :-

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('skycom_container')[0].click()")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('silentUIblocker').click()")
```

Final code

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\name\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (3)\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.implicitly_wait(30) # seconds
    driver.get('https://www.sky.com/shop/beta?s_tnt=87085:31:0')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/article/button/div[1]/div[2]/div/h2').click()
    element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/section/div/div/div/div/div[1]/article/a') 
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="polaris"]/div/div/div/section/div/div[2]/a[2]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dsl-postcode"]').send_keys("E11 2LX")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dsl-check-landline"]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dsl-addresses"]/option[2]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dsl-multiple-address-select"]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dsl-numberPortingNo"]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dsl-number-porting-submit"]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="summaryBackLink"]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="oneOffCostToolTip"]').click()
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Could you please tell me the exact code lines for python? Thanx in advance..:)

Comment: As per the below link if you have classname or id you can click directly .. refer :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987006/how-to-click-a-javascript-button-with-selenium

Comment: Is it possible for you to go through my code and help me?

Comment: can you tell me the id or class of the element which causing this error. be sure that id or class must be unique on the DOM

Comment: <div class="skycom_container">...</div> and <div id="silentUIblocker" style="display: block;"></div>. I got this from the error generated.

Comment: They are present in the dynamic content generated.

Comment: Added script in my answer. Now remove click operation from your script where you are clicking on it and replace with the code I have added in answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150942/discussion-between-sky-bird-and-shubham-jain).

Comment: you just remove accept answer for me ... any issues with code I have shared with you yesterday? .. you can't accept everyone's answer .. You have to select only one answer which works for you .. This is how stackoverflow works

Comment: No issues, it worked perfect for me. I got one part of answer from you and the other part from other reply. I didn't know i could accept only one. But, i am still waiting for the other part as the reply from you is still not able to help me.

Comment: You can create an another ticket for same. You can ask for a single issue at a ticket as per stackoverflow rules. while stack only allow you to help you in problem statement rather then writing the whole script. As your one issue is resolved. I suggest to you create an another ticket with the recent issue you are facing with the error in your question. hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try to add below imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

and insert below line just before making `click()`:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "silentUIblocker")))
```

This should allow you wait until element that intercept the click disappeared

Comment: Yeah, it works. There is another error i just added. Could you see that too?

Comment: Try to solve in the same way: `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "skycom_container")))`

Comment: Still not done..getting this error:                    
      C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.pyc in until(self, method, message) 
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Even the WebdriverWait has stopped working! Why is this even happening!!? I really need help..:(

Comment: Can you share page URL and description of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have already mentioned my code. I wanted the extract the details of different package combinations

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice your code. It seem that your issue is related to page scrolling: when you make first click page scrolled to required element to make new click. But those two clicks executed one after another disregarding whether page is already static or scrolling is in progress... So click intercepted by element that is currently visible on the same position on screen as target element. You can try to add appropriate verification to check this before making click.I think using `location_once_scrolled_into_view` property could help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150949/discussion-between-sky-bird-and-andersson).