# Instagram/Selenium not clicking accept button

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to make a simple python script that accepts follower requests. I have everything working up to the last part, where the button I need to click is not clicking.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

"""
Credentials to login to Instagram.
"""

username = "username"
password = "password"

"""
Driver finds the path where the Chrome Driver is located.
getDriver stores the URL.
driver.get loads the URL into Chrome.
"""

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'path to chrome driver')
getDriver = ("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/activity?followRequests=")
driver.get(getDriver)

"""
Loging into Instagram.
"""

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Log in')]").click()

"""
Accepts the followers. Click button. Then loops until all are accepted.
"""
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0')
for e in elements:
        e.click()
        time.sleep(2)

"""
Class name: <button class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0">Approve</button>
Xpath name: //*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/section/ul/li[2]/div[3]/div/span[1]/button
"""
```

I have tried using the class name and xpath and still no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

IDLE Output:

```
RESTART: C:\Users\Tyler\Documents\Programming\Python\AutoAccept\autoAccept.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\Documents\Programming\Python\AutoAccept\autoAccept.py", line 34, in <module>
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0')
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 571, in find_elements_by_class_name
    return self.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 983, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

HTML for button:

```
<div class="_n76vw"> == $0
        <span class="_4t1rg _ov9ai"> == $0
                <button class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0">Approve</button> == $0
        </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What error your are getting ?

Comment: IDLE prompts something, which I've added to the original post. However, the script runs fine, logs in, clicks log in button, and navigates to the link however it's not clicking the button that needs to be clicked, which is the approve one.

Comment: Seems your class name is dynamic

Comment: If the class is dynamic is there anyway to still click it?

Comment: Try to add explicit wait after login

Comment: Yes please see my answers you can use xpath

Comment: Ankur, can you explain how to "Try to add explicit wait after login?"

Comment: @Tyler, share HTML for mentioned button

Comment: I updated the post and shared the HTML for the button. I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Are those css class names randomized? The page could have some protection against automatic logins :p

Answer (score 3):

You can try this xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Approve')]").click()
```

Comment: instead of `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` I had to use `driver.find_element_by_xpath` because the first returns a list not one element.

Comment: Lifesaver. Since the format changed in June, 2022, no other method has been working.

Answer (score 0):

As right now selenium doesn't support multiple class name.If your class name includes a space, WebDriver will see it as a "compound selector". You can use cssSelector or id for selecting the webelement.

Try below code

You can try this xpath:

```
//button[@class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0" and text()="Approve"]
```

Or CSS selector:

```
._qv64e._gexxb._4tgw8._njrw0
```

As :

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//span/button [text()="Approve"])
```

and

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(._qv64e._gexxb._4tgw8._njrw0)
```

Refer this link http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: What error it give ? I have modified ans please check

Comment: There is no error being outputed. When I run t he script it navigates to the URL I specified but is still not clicking the button.

Comment: Still not working, could you put the CSS in my current code? Perhaps I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: If it's still not working my suggestion would be use JavaScript click event on that button using selenium

Comment: Refer this link https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987006/how-to-click-a-javascript-button-with-selenium&ved=2ahUKEwjourur_YfZAhWHrI8KHW6AANEQFjAAegQIEhAB&usg=AOvVaw3BDtuWBzxD90oD8oFolsDt